# Errors while building framework for macOS in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, frameworks, bridging-header

I have wrote a wrapper for SQLite3 in Swift and it works fine.

I thought of making a framework of it.

The problem is:

To use SQLite3 in swift, we should import the `sqlite3.h` using bridging header. But I there is no option for bridging header in framework project.

I have created a `.c` and `.h` and imported `sqlite3.h` in `.h` and made the `.h` public header. But it doesn't work. It still gives `use of unresolved identifier` errors.

How can I import `.c` and `.cpp` files into swift framework project?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can only use header files which are there in your project(Anyone correct me if I'm wrong). So, add the `sqlite3.h` to your project.

**Step 1:**

Search for `sqlit3.h`

Xcode.app(right-click)-> show package contents

[image]

**Step 2:**

Search for `sqlite.h` in your `Xcode.app`

[image]

**Step 3:**

Drag that file into your xcode project and select `copy items if needed`

[image]

**Step 4:**

Select the `sqlite3.h` from navigator and change it to `Public` in the right-side panel.

[image]

**Step 5:**

Import the `sqlite3.h` in the header file which Xcode has created for you. You should import it as `#import "sqlite3.h"`

[image]

**Step 6:**

Now Build the project. It should work fine.

Comment: Is there any easier method?

Comment: @unknownymouse you can directly include your source files into other projects where you want to use the sqlite3

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry to disturb you but can you help with this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741947/swift-timer-firing-before-the-specified-time-interval ?

Comment: @unknownymouse im currently busy. I will look into it.