# Swift `Timer` firing before the specified time interval

Tags: swift, macos, timer, foundation

I got a doubt about how `Timer.scheduledTimer()` fires the block of code if the execution takes more time than the specified `withTimeInterval:`.

Does the countdown to firing starts after the execution of the block or when the first statement of the block is executed?

**So I tested with the following code**:

```
//Logic is to waste the time in the block which will take more than 5 secs to run.
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true){
    timer in
    var sum = 0
    var count = 0

    print("START===================================")
    print(Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000))
    for i in 2..<100000
    {
        for j in 2..<10000
        {
            sum = i+j
        }
    }

    print(sum) // Ignore this. sum is used here so that compiler might won't be able to remove the loop in the optimisations due to unused variable reason.
    print(Int64(Date().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000))
    print("END===================================")
}

RunLoop.main.run()
```

**Output**:

```
START===================================
1507965166992
109998
1507965173888
END===================================
START===================================
1507965176993
109998
1507965183890
END===================================
START===================================
1507965186989
```

When I subtracted end-time of previous loop and start-time of current loop, I always get around 3 secs. But I have specified 5 secs. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the documentation of [`Timer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer).

> **Overview**
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> A timer is not a real-time mechanism. If a timer’s firing time occurs
>   during a long run loop callout or while the run loop is in a mode that
>   isn't monitoring the timer, the timer doesn't fire until the next time
>   the run loop checks the timer. Therefore, the actual time at which a
>   timer fires can be significantly later.
>
> ...

So, the timer doesn't execute your block of code at the exact time always. It schedules it on the run loop. If there are some important threads to execute, then your code will be delayed. So, to maintain a fixed firing time, look at specifying [tolerance](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/timer/1415085-tolerance) value.

and

> **Comparing Repeating and Nonrepeating Timers**
>
> You specify whether a timer is repeating or nonrepeating at creation
>   time. A nonrepeating timer fires once and then invalidates itself
>   automatically, thereby preventing the timer from firing again. By
>   contrast, a repeating timer fires and then reschedules itself on the
>   same run loop. A repeating timer always schedules itself based on
>   the scheduled firing time, as opposed to the actual firing time. For
>   example, if a timer is scheduled to fire at a particular time and
>   every 5 seconds after that, the scheduled firing time will always fall
>   on the original 5-second time intervals, even if the actual firing
>   time gets delayed. If the firing time is delayed so far that it passes
>   one or more of the scheduled firing times, the timer is fired only
>   once for that time period; the timer is then rescheduled, after
>   firing, for the next scheduled firing time in the future.

Here, it says that the countdown starts when the first timer is started but not when the timer has ended.

---

**For your 1st question**:

> Does the countdown to firing starts after the execution of the block
>   or when the first statement of the block is executed?

**Answer**: Neither. The countdown starts when the first timer is started.

---

**For your 2nd question**:

> When I subtracted endtime of previous loop and starttime of current
>   loop, I always get around 3 sec. But I have specified 5 sec. Why is
>   that?

**Answer**:

**1)**. As I said in your 1st question, the countdown starts after the first timer has started.

**2)**. In **Comparing Repeating and Nonrepeating Timers**, they said that if the logic takes more time than the specified time in the `timer` then it executes the code only once after the completion of the execution block and also after the specified time.

i.e.,

```
Timer interval: 5

Time for block to complete: 8

Then next code will be executed at: 8 + 2 = 10 secs(as 5 is the interval)
```

**According to your code's output**:

```
START===================================
1507965166992                           <---------+
109998                                            |
1507965173888                                     |
END===================================            |
START===================================          |
1507965176993                           <---------+
109998                                            |
1507965183890                                     |
END===================================            |
START===================================          |
1507965186989                           <---------+
```

Check the time difference of the marked arrow above. It executes the  code exactly after 10secs(which is same as the explanation I have given above).

**Tip**: Always look at and read the documentation before asking.

Answer (score -2):

Use the GCD method https://www.appcoda.com/grand-central-dispatch/ its make much better than Timer
if you want to display one by one then follow the steps below

```
let queue1 = DispatchQueue(label: "com.appcoda.queue1", qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated)
let queue2 = DispatchQueue(label: "com.appcoda.queue2", qos: DispatchQoS.userInitiated)

queue1.async{
     for i in 2..<100000 {
        queue2.async{
           for j in 2..<10000 {
             sum = i+j
           }
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: `Timer` is used to execute the code at specific time or repeating the execution with specified time interval. And G.C.D is used for multi-threading. How is your solution relates to it?

Comment: By use of GCD also we easily handle the execution of the function..!!

Comment: But how? Can you provide  a piece of code to mimic the timer functionality in GCD?

Comment: I got an answer from another user. Thanks for your time.